# VLC fullscreen - dual screen

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player, fullscreen

I work on Windows Vista. There is a TV plugged in to the computer, so that I have two screens.

How can I tell VLC (latest version, 1.1.11) to put my movies on the second screen when I change it to fullscreen?

Answer (score 2):

Move the VLC window to your second monitor then go fullscreen.

Comment: it functioned for me