# Starting VLC fullscreen on specific screen (from CLI)

Tags: windows-10, command-line, video, vlc-media-player, fullscreen

there are plenty of similar questions regarding full-screen playback and VLC, none of them answers my questions though, like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/87436/how-do-i-get-vlc-to-play-on-the-second-monitor-on-windows), ore [here](https://superuser.com/questions/314899/vlc-fullscreen-dual-screen)

I can connect 3 displays to my laptop, and for presentation purposes i want to make a batch file which opens a fullscreen video on one of them (which is connected to a projector). I would like to use a batch file which immediately opens up the video on the desired screen, the command here ALMOST does this:
https://superuser.com/a/193342/228841

Additionally, the VLC manual offers this command:

```
--directx-device=<string>
          Name of desired display device
          In a multiple monitor configuration, you can specify the Windows device name of the display that you want the video window to open on. For example, "\\.\DISPLAY1" or "\\.\DISPLAY2".
```

So i tried this batch file:

```
set vlcPath="C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
%vlcPath% %1  --directx-device="\\.\DISPLAY2" --fullscreen --no-video-title-show --no-embedded-video --no-qt-fs-controller
```

Which doesnt work, the video opens on the primary display. 
My feeling is that the Display names might be different in Windows 10 then previous Windows versions, but i havent found a way yet to get a list of connected displays from the CLI.

So, where can i find the Display Names and how can pass them to VLC from a command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the display names in the options here:[image]

It's basically `DISPLAY1`, `DISPLAY2` etc

So the command that works for me is `--directx-device=DISPLAY5`

Answer (score 2):

The approach in [@krasatos' 2021-03 answer](https://superuser.com/a/1632952/) to use `--directx-device=DISPLAY<#>` no longer appears to work.

The following solution is working for me `--qt-fullscreen-screennumber=n` where `n` is the display number starting from `0`

For example:

- 1st Display: `--qt-fullscreen-screennumber=0`
- 2nd Display: `--qt-fullscreen-screennumber=1`

For reference, the way I found this was to:

1. Find the VLC preferences file `vlcrc` located in `%appdata%/vlc/`
2. In the GUI's "Preferences" configure VLC to use `DISPLAY1`
3. Make a backup copy of the `vlcrc` file
4. Repeat #1-3 but configure it to use `DISPLAY2` instead of `DISPLAY2`
5. Diff the two backed-up `vlcrc` files